# Localhost url rewriting: mydomain/collection/resource

Tags: url-rewriting

My current project urls look like this:

> localhost/mydomain/public/collection/resource.

I have several PHP projects running out of localhost at the moment. I would like the url for this project to be as it would in production so I'm not coding around the url. Is there a way to get this to be mydomain/collection/resource?

Comment: Create a utility method called (for example) as `url('collection/resource')` and then pull config values in that method to generate an absolute url. This will let you specify protocol, port, domain, and leading path easily on any environment.

Comment: Any way to do this with apache config. Url rewriting for example?

Comment: You could potentially mangle outgoing html via apache configs but that's not a great solution and could cause some really odd and hard to track down bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to implement apache vHosts:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    ServerName mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/Bitnami/wampstack-5.6.21-2/apache2/htdocs/mydomain/public"
</VirtualHost>

<Directory "C:/Bitnami/wampstack-5.6.21-2/apache2/htdocs/mydomain/public">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```